# Tkinter Labelframe strange behavior : border color disappear when applying text in label

Tags: tkinter

My label frames can only handle the `highlightbackground` and `highlightcolor` options as long as I don't put some text in the `text` option.

Here is my code, try by youserself, if you add some text in the `LabelFrame` the border disappear ...

```py
import tkinter as tk

def change_bg(widget):
    widget['highlightbackground'] = 'red'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="", height=100, width=100,
        highlightbackground="green", highlightcolor="green", highlightthickness=1, bd= 0)
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Paint")
    button['command'] = lambda wgt=frame : change_bg(wgt)

    frame.pack()
    button.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

[image] [image]

Comment: For me, when I click the button, the highlight colour changes to red no matter what the text is. What happens to your window?

Comment: It's working for me too as long as the text is empty. If I put something in the text of the label I don''t even have a frame border anymore. It's all white.

Comment: That doesn't happen on Windows 10 so it might be an OS specific bug.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this when tested in Mac, but it works just fine on Windows. I believe it's one of those things that Mac simply doesn't support. You can try nesting the `LabelFrame` inside a `Frame` with a border and change its background color, something like this

```py
import tkinter as tk

def change_bg(widget):
    widget['bg'] = 'red'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    base_frame=tk.Frame(root,bd=1,bg='green')
    base_frame.pack()
    frame = tk.LabelFrame(base_frame, text="asdas", height=100, width=100,bd= 0)
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Paint")
    button['command'] = lambda wgt=base_frame : change_bg(wgt)

    frame.pack()
    button.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to find a workaround on Mac using the clam theme :

This one below works for me so far and allows to color multiple Labelframe with different color including Label and bordercolor.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


    root = Tk()
    
    edit_labelframe_color_style = ttk.Style()
    edit_labelframe_color_style.theme_use('clam') #only theme to handle bordercolor for labelframe
    
    edit_labelframe_color_style.configure('red.TLabelframe', bordercolor='red',background='white')
    edit_labelframe_color_style.configure('red.TLabelframe.Label', foreground='red',background='white')
    
    edit_labelframe_color_style.configure('green.TLabelframe', bordercolor='green',background='white')
    edit_labelframe_color_style.configure('green.TLabelframe.Label', foreground='green',background='white')
    
    labelframe = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Group", style='red.TLabelframe',height=200, width=400)
    labelframe.grid(padx=20, pady=20)
    labelframe.grid_propagate(0)
    
    labelframe1 = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Group", style='green.TLabelframe',height=200, width=400)
    labelframe1.grid(padx=20, pady=200)
    labelframe1.grid_propagate(0)
    
    
    
    root.mainloop()
```